# Seamless flow to/from virtual camera motion to motion tracked clip

Tags: camera, tracking

I have a virtual environment, use curves to give camera movement.  I would like to transition to a tracked camera of actual footage from the same scene.

So far, I can get tracked footage the key points onto the graph editor. For follow curve in the virtual movement, i can not get the data for camera position (xyz=000).

I'm not sure if i am going about this the correct way.

Comment: not sure if I get your question, but solved camera animation is stored as a constraint, not in transformation channels... you could animate the constraint influence to zero and see if it helps to transition, or you could directly convert the constraint motion to real fcurves -look for operator in constraints panel- if this does not help maybe try to better explain your problem

Comment: After 'set tracking scene' the camera path is displayed, a constraint, not a line, as you say, thanks.  In constraint tab - camera solver - there is Constraint to f curve.  This gives data.  Can i then construct a curve from this data? Then extend it with a curve to add additional frames?  The extended 'curve' will be for camera views of the 3d virtual environment.    Maybe i'm over thinking things, and it will be better to splice the two clips together.

Comment: if you want your -now- keyframed camera to end in (0,0,0) you need to go fcurves editor, select one by one the transform curves -hide the others-, go to end frame and move up or down all keyframes, aligning last keyframe... for instance if your camera ends in (-50,25,15) you select all X keyframes and type G Y 50 to move up, then select all Y keyframes and type G Y -25, and with your Z keyframes selected type G Y -15... that will keep the curves but they will end in (0,0,0)... same for rotation channels, but I don't know if that's what you are asking... sure you can add new keyframes to camera

Comment: but yes, maybe just have 2 cameras and switch -you can do it with markers in timeline-